# What is the best way to share common code (such as domain classes) between two or more projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

We are developing a Web application consisting of two Eclipse projects. One project is an HTTP-based <strike>RESTful</strike> Web service; the other project is a Web site. Both will be deployed as WARs. Initially, both will be deployed under the same application server instance, but eventually they'll be on separate boxes.

The Web site app consumes the <strike>RESTful</strike> WS app. Obviously, there will be code--specifically, domain classes--that are common to both projects. For instance, there might be a resource located at <app>/users which exposes CRUD operations on User objects; to update a user, the Web site app would POST an XML-marshalled User object to <app>/users. Doing a GET to <app>/users/1 would return an XML-marshalled User object.

Obviously, having a User class in both projects would be pretty stupid for a variety of reasons. So I'm wondering what is the best way to go about this? Putting the common code in a JAR that's shared between the two projects is what I have done in the past, but is there a better or easier way?

Edit: Removed RESTful references. Semantics aside, what is the right way to share common code between two Eclipse projects?

Answer (score 14):

**Separation of concerns**

Actually creating a third project and adding project dependencies is the best way, because [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) isn't only a principle for classes but also for software modules. It creates some advantages:

- Less code to read to learn the ropes of one project.
- Better dependency control, because you could leave out some inter-project dependencies, so that using classes of the wrong module isn't possible.
- Duplicating code is awful.

**Project Structure**

Make sure you're not creating one big "*utility*" project, but rather domain-specific projects, like *user management* or *addressbook*.

In your case, it could be

- *user-api* contains User transfer object
- *user-service* provides CRUD operations
- *webapp* (or *user-client*) calls user-service.

**Other Build Systems**

When moving to continuous integration you'll need to use a better build system than Eclipse, but the principles are the same. You'll create small modules with minimal dependencies.

The most popular Build Systems for Java projects are [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org). Each has its own way to define module dependencies.

**Project references in Eclipse**

To tell Eclipse about project dependencies, right click on the project, open the properties and switch to the project references. Here you could mark dependencies, so that code changes will take effect immediately without copying a JAR file manually.

[image: Project references menu]

Comment: Can you please clarify how is this different from Java Build Path > Projects and adding dependent project ?

Answer (score 7):

Imho, this depends on your **build system**, not your IDE.

So, if you

- use plain Eclipse to build and like to keep things simple, just add a third project and add a dependecy.
- use osgi, you'd properly already have created a new osgi project.
- use a build tool, like maven or gradle, then setup a multi-project build.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you create a third project (e.g. *core* or *shared*) which contains the shared code. Just depend on it from both your projects.

Comment: simple and clear. Also, one could pick one of the two projects - maybe the smaller one - and focus there all the common classes, so project 2 will use project 1 as a lib, and project 1 will be whatever it is and act as a lib also.
Not very orthodox maybe but you save deployment and maintenance for a third prj.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another project (i.e. shared). All of my SERVER-CLIENT app i do like that.

[image: Here is a sample of an EJB app]

Basicaly, *shared* module has the EJB interfaces that are used by *client* and implemented by *ejbModule*

Answer (score 1):

How do you use third party jars? Think about your common code to be third party jar and apply the same rule to your projects. You can use dependency management tool like maven in order to keep versioning in order.

If you want to upgrade to an Application Server where you can deploy EARs you can put the common code in a jar which is a dependency of your EAR... so other WAR projects in your EARs can use the common code.

You can also give a try to OSGI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing domain classes between a client and server in a RESTful system you are defeating the point of REST.  The REST constraints are designed to allow a client and server system to independently evolve by ensuring that the only coupling between the two systems is confined to media types and link relations.

If you need to share domain objects,  forget about REST, it is going to me more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an answer. Plus—why forget about REST? What if he wants to support other consumers over his REST Web service, and his Web app is just another consumer? The OP didn't state he *needed* to share domain objects. To me it just seems that, rather than repeating himself in both WAR projects typing in *exactly* the same domain object classes OP is, indeed, better off placing them in a shared JAR, which is pretty much the standard way to do it.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael  "A REST API should never have typed resources that are significant to the client"  http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: AlistairIsrael, this is precisely our intentions. The REST service is the workhorse, the Web app is a consumer, a desktop app will eventually be a consumer, and of course clients will be consumers.

In the Web app, data must be transferred from the HTML form to the REST consumption call in _something_--it seemed to me that reusing the domain classes that the REST service exposes (and accepts as the request body with POST and PUT operations) was the obvious choice.

Comment: @Darrel Miller, the only client the typed resources are truly significant to is the Web app (internal significance); 3rd party clients, e.g. customers, can use the resources anyway they see fit and responses include enumeration of available resources. (If we were so inclined, XSLT and some JS could be used to have the REST service fulfill the basic operations that the Web app performs.)

In any case, semantics aside, what would be the way to go here?

Comment: You can share the classes using a third project with rest without scarifying the possibility to evolve independently in the future. Tomorrow you can remake one of the projects in another language and you can still use the same REST interface while the third project makes no sense anymore byt the REST service is still doing it's work.

Answer (score 0):

there are several possible ways to do this, and depending on your specific situation and requirements, some might be better than other.

in all cases, i would strongly recommend a system that understands version numbers.

a classic way to do this would be to use maven. also, it is very well integrated in eclipse and you can structure your modules as part of one parent project, such as:

```
project-parent
    project-website1
    project-website2
    project-controllers
    project-model
    [...]
```

internally, these modules can then depend on each other. you can go as far as separating interfaces from the implementation:

```
project-parent
    project-website1
    project-website2
    project-api
    project-api-impl
    [...]
```

and then depending on the api module most of the time. maven also has a few mechanisms for dealing with WAR files.

this (single-project) approach is probably ideal for a very small development team. the main drawback is that it is quite unpractical to release things separately - a bugfix in the implementation that only affects website2 would also require a release of website1.

also, the separation tends to be less clear in this, making it potentially too easy to move stuff into the shared modules that shouldn't really be there.

another pattern would be:

```
 project1-parent
      project1-webapp
      project1-specifics
      [...]

 project2-parent
      project2-webapp
      project2-specifics
      [...]

 common-parent
      common-api
      common-impl
      common-model
      [...]
```

this makes the separation a bit clearer, and you can release things separately. also (although this is probably not recommended under normal circumstances), project1-webapp could depend on an older or newer version of the common module than project2-webapp. maven can be found here:

```
https://maven.apache.org/
```

another toolset that might help you deal with versioning is:

```
https://gradle.org/
```

to make the most of these, you might also want to look into using git with gitflow:

```
http://git-scm.com/
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/
```

and understand how to use this to deal with versioning and releasing.

personally, i found it VERY confusing when i first started out - but it all makes a lot of sense now.