# How to implement my own CMS hosted on a remote domain in all my projects?

Tags: php, apache, api, server, content-management-system

So, I'm developing my own CMS which dynamically adjusts to the settings I have set on a specific domain.

I just developed this whole CMS on my local machine and now facing the problem that I have multiple projects, each on a different domain (same host provider though, don't know if that's relevant?). On my localhost it's no problem because I just point to the specific CMS folder.

__

Example: My CMS Files are in a subdirectory of **www.mycms.com** like `www.mycms.com/cms/` and my project ist hosted on **www.project-a.com**.

Now I assumed I just need to include my multiple CMS files like `www.mycms.com/cms/classes/user.php`, etc.

Since this gives me a `permission denied` error and everyone on the web seems to be against `allow_url_fopen` because of security risks, I need to know if I have other possibilities to make this work without putting all the files of `/cms/` into each domain each time. Because that would force me to upload all CMS files all the time to each domain seperately, even if I just change minor things.

I don't know if this is compareable to an API like the Google Maps API or something where you also just include remote files? (As far as I know)

What are my options? And if there are no options left, should I reconsider using `allow_url_fopen` but implementing security methods to avoid attacks, etc?

Comment: Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341962/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-common-code-such-as-domain-classes-between-two-o

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me much since this is about Java and there are several import techniques like Gradle to achieve this goal.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I tried to be as specific as I could be since I also don't find much possibilities on the web for my issue. In short I just want to include remote files of a specific domain to implement my CMS dynamically on Project A, Project B, etc.

Comment: you would usually just copy the files to the separate locations

Comment: But than I'd have to put all files of `/cms/` into each domain of each project each time. That would force me to upload all CMS files all the time to each domain seperately, even if I just change minor things.

Comment: Check, how they did that in WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network . Take the idea and implement it in your CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on following assumptions:

- You have kind of root-access to your server and you are able to enter your webserver's configuration.
- You have rather low experience in web-based development (deduced from the fact, that you build your own CMS; `allow_url_fopen` seems a viable option to you, beside that `allow_url_include` is what you're actually seeking for; `allow_url_include` won't magically connect to the remote server and load the php-files like server-side; `allow_url_include` should definitely be disabled, due to security risks; `allow_url_include` could also greatly reduce the performance of your project; your idea of what is a webservice is derived from Google Maps API) - no intent to offend!

Let me address the issues with `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include`:

- `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` would require you to open a potential security risk.:

  - `allow_url_*` would require you to expose the source-code of your application via http. Based on my deduced assumption, that you're rather beginner, I imply the risk, that a potential attacker would find a way, how to formulate some hack very easy. Unfair generalization, but this is almost always the case when I review source-code of younger developers.
  - You will have a second, potentially hackable layer of your application, that could emit all sorts of php-code.
- You have an additional chain-part, that could have downtime due to maintenance or hardware-/software-problems. This is also the case when making content accessible via a webservice (REST, etc).
- `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include`, or even a webservice could noticeably reduce the performance of your CMS, since all files, that are subjected to inclusion, would be streamed over network instead of the (usually much better connected) local storage.

Solution 1) The most common solution is, to configure your domain's DNS A and AAAA-Records to point all to the same server-ip and configure your webserver (eg apache, nginx/varnish) to direct all traffic to a single virtual-host. Your CMS then has to deal with requests from different *origin addresses*. You can deliver the appropriate content based on, whats in the super-global `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`-variable. Beware, that this variable could be named differently, if your server-environment is behind a reverseproxy (you would know this; this is not different per visitor then).

- Step1: DNS-Resolution: Your project-a.xyz points to the ip of your cms' server.
- Step2: Your webserver knowns, that it has to do something with project-a.xyz
- Step3: Your webserver directs the request to your CMS
- Step4: Your CMS resolves the actually requested host from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`
- Step5: Your CMS emits the content, that belongs to the requested host-name

Solution 2) If you want those projects to be physically separated as your requests suggests, you can take a look at various deployment-systems, that would enable to you push changes to multiple destinations. Your CMS should be built in a way, that treats cm-system-core-files (PHP-Files) and actual content differently and is able to update core-files without affecting content. You don't have pretty much options here. You could use SCM-Systems like Git or SVN to sync changes with remote projects easily, but this is rather discouraged.

Solution 3) You can indeed build some kind of webservice (REST is a often used technique these days). So the web-project hosted on project-a.zyx would be a rather simple thin-client, that mostly redirects requests to some rest-endpoint. You would normally also want some kind of https-based authentication here. This would require your clients to be able to request content (not actual source-code!) from another endpoint via HTTP (which is sometimes disabled on shared hosting environments), optionally make some transformation on that content and emit it. Since your requests seems to imply, that this is not the ideal option, you should really look into the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Don’t do this.

Each site should have independent libraries. Imagine one day you decide to make a change to add a new feature or change a feature in your CMS for *one* of yours sites. Suddenly you have to test this change on *all* of your sites before you can roll it out. It’s a better idea to version all your files and then deploy those files to each site as it becomes practical to do so.

2.) If you *must* do this, and your hosting provider has one file space for all your domains you can do it, no problem.
e.g., create a file structure that looks like:

```
~/public_html/cms/
~/public_html/project-a.com/
~/public_html/project-b.com/
…
```

For each website (in a config file just for that site or possibly in the index.php if all traffic routes through that):

```
define( ‘CMS_PATH’, /root/path/to/users/your-user-name/public_html/cms/‘ );
```

Now each site can access CMS files as:

```
require CMS_PATH . ‘classes/user.php’;
```

You can also get a little clever here so you don't have to define the path for every site by hand. If you're defining it in the file `~/public_html/project-a.com/index.php` you could use

```
define( ‘CMS_PATH’, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/cms/' );
```